# An enclosed img tag will not show up if I include a query string in its surrounding a tag

Tags: html, image, erb

I have td items that display checkers like so (please forgive its beastly length):

```
<td id= <%= "#{LETTERS[square - 1]}#{row}" %> class= "open-square"><a href="/gameplay/<%= "#{LETTERS[square - 1]}#{row}" %>" ><img src="/img/black_checker.png" alt="black checker" /></a></td>
```

when I change it to include a querystring in the href like this:

```
<td id= <%= "#{LETTERS[square - 1]}#{row}" %> class= "open-square"><a href="/gameplay/<%= "#{LETTERS[square - 1]}#{row}" %><%= "?board = #{game_state_string(@board)}" %>><img src="/img/red_checker.png" alt="red checker" /></a></td>
```

it doesn't show the img. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're missing a quote.

You have this:

```
<%= "?board = #{game_state_string(@board)}" %>>
```

Try adding one in here:

```
<%= "?board = #{game_state_string(@board)}" %>">  <-- right there
```

If that's not it, I think I'd need to see the code as rendered.  Also, it looks like your id on the td elements is being output without quotes.  Like all HTML attributes, it should be in quotes.  This isn't causing your problem, it's just a side note.

```
<td id="<%= "#{LETTERS[square - 1]}#{row}" %>" class="open-square">
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Even though I feel like a dumb-ass forgetting a character, I do love an easy fix.

Comment: Easy fixes always make me happy, even if I do kick myself a little for needing them.  Glad to assist.